# Writeback services in Microsoft Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-mobile

How can you do writeback in Power BI?

Does Power BI also support writeback like Microstrategy?
I couldn't find any solution from PowerBI. I saw a workaround using PowerApps, where they created a PowerApp and embedded that in PowerBI and used Flow to automate the task to write back into databases, but it is not so feasible.

Are there any other working solutions?

Comment: I would recommend you look at http://poweronbi.com/powerbi-visual-planning/

Answer (score 3):

There isn't any official way to write-back.

You can do the same approach as PowerApp visuals do. In your custom visual, you can trigger an action to writes back to your SQL DB or whatever other source you have, e.g. Push Data Rows or refresh.

You can also trigger a 'Refresh Now' call via Power BI REST APIs to update your dataset from the DB.

If you're in embed mode, there is also a JS SDK call to `refresh()` the view such that the visuals will now display the new data.

See what [PowerOn](http://poweronbi.com/) does in a similar manner.